# Include architecture specific files in UWP application package

Tags: .net, visual-studio, uwp

I'm using 3rd party .NET library that is essentially a wrapper over c++ library.
This library is not NuGet package. I have only the C++ libraries for different architectures (ARM, x86, x64) and the managed library.

I have referenced the managed library in my project, and I have created Post-build event that copies the correct C++ library to the build directory:

> xcopy /Y "$(ProjectDir)ExternalReferences\NoesisGUI\uwp_$(Platform)*.*" "$(TargetDir)"

The problem I have is that this C++ library is not copied to the **AppX** folder when deploying, so I get *System.DllNotFoundException* .

What is the correct way to include architecture specific files in the application package?

This is the project folder structure with C++ libraries:

[image: Project folder structure with C++ libraries]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for scripting, it's easier to just add those as `Content` of the project.

First, move your ExternalReferences folder outside of the project. The parent folder (which by default is where you have the .sln file) should do fine.

Manually edit your .csproj file and add the following before the ending `</Project>` tag:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="..\ExternalReferences\NoesisGUI\uwp_$(Platform)\Noesis.dll">
    <Link>Noesis.dll</Link>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

This will include the Noesis.dll file in the project taking into account the platform it is currently being built for.

**Note:** above I used "..\" to use the parent folder, make sure to change this if you moved the folder somewhere else!

Comment: Actually you would also need to select Build Action to Content.
But this will not work for me, because I have 3 different libraries for 3 architectures. So I have to place them in subfolders.
I have added my folder structure to my question.
I need to include only the correct library based on architecture I'm building for.

Comment: @Kenshin if set Build Action to "Content", there's should be no need for Copy to Output Directory to "Always" as that is pretty much the default

Comment: When I have switched only the Copy to Output Directory to "Always", the file was copied to build directory, but was not copied to AppX directory when deployed.

Comment: Ah fair enough, I forgot about the package! :) Updating my answer then!

Comment: Thank you Pedro Lamas, your updated answer solved my problem. It's strange that Visual Studio does not have any build in configuration settings for this requirement.